# Is a = b == c possible to write in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

if b == c then write Boolean in a

is that possible to write in c#.net?

Comment: Try it yourself and see...

Comment: Note that the meaning is clearer if you write `a = (b==c);`

Comment: Get [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and you'll get even quicker answers to such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but why didn't you just *try* it? And not only is it *possible* to write it, but it's actually legal C#. It will assign the value of the boolean expression `b == c` to the variable `a`, which I'm assuming you declared, implicitly or explicitly, as `bool`. Stylistically, I prefer to see

```
a = (b == c);
```

or

```
var a = (b == c);
```

or

```
bool a = (b == c);
```

I think these are easier to read than without the parentheses.

Comment: Also most efficient way to right this is  a = b == c;

Answer (score 5):

Yes because the equality operator (==) has a higher precedence than the assignment one (=), so it gets evaluated first.

Comment: +1 Very good point! [7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes?

What is the problem?

```
var b = 1;
var c = 1;
var a = b == c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're getting at here but the following is valid:

```
var a = (b == c)
```

where a will be true or false depending on whether b and c are equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
The compiler will first evaluate b==c and then assign the value to a.